# Did the now closed pro-Saudi think tank Arabia Foundation register as a foreign agent?

Tags: united-states, media, saudi-arabia, foreign-interference

The Washington-based pro-Saudi Arabia Foundation think tank [closed](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/pro-saudi-arabia-think-tank-washington-shuts-down) in the aftermath of the Khashoggi murder. I'm curious however: was the Foundation required to list itself as a foreign agent under FARA, prior to its closure of course?

I suspect the answer is no [because](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/10/23/shihabi-saudi-arabia-washington-ambassador-933951)

> In a WhatsApp conversation with POLITICO this week, Shihabi [the Foundation's head] noted that he does not accept any Saudi government money, and expressed no doubts about his ongoing support of the embattled Saudi monarchy.
>
> He describes the foundation as an independent think tank funded by himself and other Saudi businessmen. The foundation doesn’t take Saudi government money, Shihabi says, though he acknowledges that he informed Saudi officials about his plans to establish the foundation, partly to ensure financial support from other Saudis.